# Why am I having trouble filtering samples from a bed file?

Tags: genetics

I am trying to filter a BED file that was downloaded. I am trying to filter it with plink but to no avail. I can get the commands to 'work' but the program is not filtering any samples as the output is the same as the input. I have also

This is what I am trying to do:

--bfile SouthernArc_Public --keep sampleids.txt --make-bed --allow-no-sex --out filtered
PLINK v1.90b6.21 64-bit (19 Oct 2020)          [www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/](http://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/)
(C) 2005-2020 Shaun Purcell, Christopher Chang   GNU General Public License v3
Logging to filtered.log.
Options in effect:
--allow-no-sex
--bfile SouthernArc_Public
--keep sampleids.txt
--make-bed
--out filtered

32011 MB RAM detected; reserving 16005 MB for main workspace.
1233013 variants loaded from .bim file.
5940 people (3341 males, 2505 females, 94 ambiguous) loaded from .fam.
Ambiguous sex IDs written to filtered.nosex .
5940 phenotype values loaded from .fam.
Error: No people remaining after --keep.

I know that the sample names are correct as I did a grep on the SouthernArc_Public.fam file to make sure my sample names match. For instance, here is my input file for the --keep command:
head sampleids.txt
I15705  I15705
I13838  I13838
I13840  I13840
I14689  I14689
I8471   I8471
I14691  I14691
I17622  I17622
I14690  I14690
I14692  I14692
I16251  I16251

I know that I15705 is in the ped file. Thus, I am not sure why it is saying no people are remaining.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!